# react-navigation Drawer and Stack nested

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to accomplish the most commont android structure: a drawer navigator with an header (stackNavigator).

The app is very simple: it is a dictionary and shows a list of item grouped by first letter (`BrowseScreen`) and also it allows a search by keyword (`SearchScreen`, someone call this Master–detail pattern).
Starting from those 2 screens, I have to be able to reach the `ItemScreen` (which shows the details of a single term).

How can I structure this in react-navigator 3? This is my attempt, but I'm not sure it's the best way, and also I don't know where to place `ItemScreen`. No drawer item should be active while I'm on an `ItemScreen`.

```
const RootDrawer = createDrawerNavigator(
    {

        Home: {
            screen: createStackNavigator({
                Home: { screen: Home },
                //Browse: { screen: Browse },
                //Search: { screen: Search }
            }, {
                initialRouteName: 'Home',

            })
        },
        Browse: {
            screen: createStackNavigator({
                Browse: { screen: Browse }, //it shows a grid of buttons with the alphabet
                Search: { screen: Search }, //it shows the items by a First letter 
            }, {
                initialRouteName: 'Browse',
            })

        },
        Search: {
            screen: createStackNavigator({
                Search: { screen: Search}
            }, {
                initialRouteName: 'Search',
            })
        },
        Bookmarks: {
            screen: createStackNavigator({
                Bookmark: { screen: Bookmarks },
                Item: { screen: ItemScreen  },
            }, {
                initialRouteName: 'Bookmark',
            })
        }
    },
    {
        mode: 'modal',
        headerMode: 'screen' ,
        initialRouteName: 'Home',
    }
);
```

Comment: Sounds achievable but i am kind of lost you with all these many routes, can you try with explain with a smaller example? :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is already the minimal example: there are just 3 views actually (other than `Home` and `Bookmarks` which don't matter right now): `Browse` shows a list of buttons (A,B,C..) to allows browsing by letter; `Search` for a search by keyword, `Item` for showing the item details.. The `Item` screen should be reachable from `Search` and `Browse` both.
I want to define correctly those routes in order to avoid unexpected behaviour with backbutton..